# how to geocode lat and long coordinates from an address search in php

Tags: geocoding

I am trying to enter new locations into a database and would like the lat and long coordinates entered correctly for mapping purposes.I have researched Googles help forum on the subject and came up with this code.

Currently, I have a table for back up that has a generic lat and long code if the address is not successful through my google maps call.  That is working, but I would like the exact coordinates if possible and the google maps call does nothing.  Here is my code.  (I have taken out my google aps key and substituted "my key"

```
if($facility_enter){
//GEOCODE
define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.com");
define("KEY", "my key");

// Do API find, returning address and id

// Initialize delay in geocode speed
$delay = 0;
$base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/geo?output=xml" . "&key=" . KEY;
//Get Address
$full_address = $_POST['fac_add'] . ' ' . $_POST['fac_city'] . ' ' .  
$_POST['fac_state'] . ' ' . 
$_POST['fac_zip'];
$prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$full_address);
$request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . urlencode($prepAddr);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
$status = $xml->Response->Status->code;
//if successful
if (strcmp($status, "200") == 0) {
  $coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;
  $coordinatesSplit = split(",", $coordinates);
  $lat = $coordinatesSplit[1];
  $lng = $coordinatesSplit[0];
}
//otherwise just pull the generic zip code coords from the database
else{
    $zip_sql = 'SELECT lat,lng FROM blahblah.zips WHERE zip = "' . $_POST['fac_zip'] . 
    '"';
    $zip_res = mysql_query($zip_sql,$my_db);
    $coords = mysql_fetch_array($zip_res);
    $lat = $coords['lat'];      
    $lng = $coords['lng'];
}
```

Comment: Could someone tell me what I am missing here?  Is there an easier way to do this?  I have researched this all over the internet, but can't find how to combine the address, city, state and zip correctly.  Did I do this correct?  If so, why can't I pull the lat and long with this code?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I figured it out....Here is the code that worked for me. {
  $address = $_POST['fac_add'] . ' ' . $_POST['fac_city'] . ' ' . $_POST['fac_state'] . ' ' . $_POST['fac_zip'];
  $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
   $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
   $output= json_decode($geocode);
   $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
  $lng = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
 }